# GORM mapping: make an index unique

Tags: grails, mapping, grails-orm

I'm feeling a little slow today. I'm trying to do something that I think is very simple. I have a Domain class with a property called 'name'. I want 'name' to have an index, and I want the index to require that the 'name' is unique. I've set the unique constraint and tried creating an index. I can't make sense out of the Gorm docs as to how I add the unique attribute to the index. Here's some code:

```
class Project {
    String name

    static hasMany = [things:Things]

    static mapping = {
        name index:'name_idx'
    }
    static constraints = {
        name(unique:true)
    }
}
```

All is well with the above, except when do "show indexes from project" in mysql it shows my name key as not unique. I know the problem is that I am not specifying unique in the mapping, but quite frankly the docs for gorm are making my head hurt. I see all kinds of stuff about columns, but I can't find a single example anywhere on the web that shows what I want to do. I don't need complex mappings or compound keys, I just want to know the syntax to add the unique attribute to the mapping declaration above. Any advice welcome.

I also did a grails export-schema and see the following:

```
create index name_idx on project (name);
```

Nothing in that to indicate this index requires unique values

A related followup question would be once I succeed in making that index unique, what type of error should I expect when I go to save a Project instance and the name is not unique? Is there a specific exception thrown? I realize that even if I check that a given 'name' is unique there's still a possibility that by the time I save it there may be a row with that name.

I'm quite sure the syntax to do what I want is simple but I just can't find a simple example to educate myself with. I've been to [this](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/unique.html) page but it doesn't explain HOW the uniqueness is enforced. I'd like to enforce it at the name index level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indexColumn allows additional options to be configured. This may be what you're looking for.

```
static mapping = {
    name indexColumn:[name:'name_idx', unique:true]
}
```

[Grails Documentation for indexColumn](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/indexColumn.html)

Comment: Thank Derek. This indeed seems right. I guess my hangup was I didn't understand why I couldn't do it with the simpler syntax, but at the end of the day this isn't all that much different! I voted this as the "right" answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked for your Rich. Since this was your own question, instead of voting, you should Accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you put only the **unique** constraint the GORM send DDL to create an unique index on database.

```
static constraints = {
   name nullable: false, unique: true
}
```

Comment: And will automatically check this constraint on validation step(+1 query)